# Python Dictionary Throwing KeyError for Some Reason

Tags: python, dictionary

In some code I pass a dictionary (TankDict) a string from a list. This throws a KeyError, no matter what letter I put in. When I copied and pasted the dictionary out of the context of the program and passed in the same letters from a list, they came out correctly. I have also run `type(TankDict)` and it comes back as 'dict'.
Here is the dictionary:
    `TankDict = {'E':0, 'F':1, 'G':2, 'H':3, 'I':4, 'J':5,
                       'K':6, 'L':7, 'M':8, 'N':9,
                       'O':10, 'P':11, 'Q':12, 'R':13, 'S':14, 'T':15,
                       'U':16, 'V':17, 'W':18, 'X':19}`

The error:
    `enter code herechannelData[1] = tank_address_dict[channelData[1]]
    KeyError: 'L'`
(tank_address_dict is a function argument into which TankDict is passed)

the contents of channelData: `['447', 'L', '15', 'C']`

Can anyone tell me the (probably simple) reason that this happens?

EDIT: Code!

This is the function where the error is:

```
def getTankID(channel,tank_address_dict,PTM_dict,channel_ref):
rawChannelData = 'NA' 
for line in channel_ref:
    if str(channel) in line: rawChannelData = line
if(rawChannelData == 'NA'): return -1;
channelData = rawChannelData.split(' ')
channelData.extend(['',''])
channelData[1] = channelData[1][:-1]
channelData[3] = channelData[1][-1]
channelData[1] = channelData[1][:-1]
channelData[2] = channelData[1][1:]
channelData[1] = channelData[1][:1]
print channelData #debug
print 'L' in tank_address_dict
print 'E' in tank_address_dict
print 'O' in tank_address_dict
print 'U' in tank_address_dict
print type(tank_address_dict)
channelData[1] = tank_address_dict[channelData[1]]
channelData[3] = PTM_dict[channelData[3]]
return(channelData[1:])
```

This is the function that calls it:

```
def runFile(model, datafile, time_scale, max_PEs, tank_address_dict, PMT_dict, channel_ref):
#add initSerial for ser0-4
while(True):   
    raw_data = datafile.readline() #intake data
    if(raw_data == ''): break #End while loop if the file is done
    data = raw_data.split(' ')  #break up the parts of each line
    del data[::2]   #delete the human formatting
    data[2] = data[2][:-1] #rm newline (NOTE: file must contain blank line at end!)
    TankID = getTankID(data[0], tank_address_dict, PMT_dict,channel_ref)
    if(TankID == -1):
        print '!---Invalid channel number passed by datafile---!'; break #check for valid TankID
    model[TankID[0]][TankID[1]][TankID[2]] = scale(data[2],(0,max_PEs),(0,4096))
    createPackets(model)
    #updateModel(ser0,ser1,ser2,ser3,ser4,packet)
    data[2] = data[2]*time_scale #scale time
    time.sleep(data[2]) #wait until the next event
    print data #debug 
if(TankID != -1): print '---File',datafile,'finished---' #report errors in file run
else: print '!---File',datafile,'finished with error---!'
```

And this is the code that calls that:

```
import hawc_func
import debug_options
#begin defs
model = hawc_func.createDataStruct() #create the data structure
TankDict = hawc_func.createTankDict() #tank grid coordinate conversion table
PTMDict = hawc_func.createPMTDict() #PMT conversion table
log1 = open('Logs/log1.txt','w') #open a logfile
data = open('Data/event.txt','r') #open data
channel_ref = open('aux_files/channel_map.dat','r')
time_scale = 1 #0-1 number to scale nano seconds? to seconds
#end defs
hawc_func.runFile(model,data,4000,TankDict,PTMDict,time_scale,channel_ref)

#hawc_func.runFile(model,data,TankDict,PTMDict)
#close files
log1.close()
data.close()
#end close files
print '-----Done-----' #confirm tasks finished
```

tank_address_dict is created through this function, run by the 3rd block of code, then passed on through the other two:

```
def createTankDict():
    TankDict = {'E':0, 'F':1, 'G':2, 'H':3, 'I':4, 'J':5,
               'K':6, 'L': 7, 'M':8, 'N':9,
               'O':10, 'P':11, 'Q':12, 'R':13, 'S':14, 'T':15,
               'U':16, 'V': 17, 'W':18, 'X':19}
    return TankDict
```

Comment: Please show your actual code along with the complete error message.

Comment: Can you show your code? The function call, and the function definition?

Comment: You say `tank_addres_dict()` takes a dictionary as an argument, and then you pass it a string?

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing unicode and ascii strings?

Comment: give me one more minute to add the code... got my revisions mixed up

Comment: Please update your indentation...

Comment: Can you provide code for tank_address_dict? since TankDict[channelData[1]] returns 7 without error

Comment: @Nathan Ernst Would this be because the file is formatted differently than the dictionary? because just trying the `print 'L' in tank_address_dict` would account for that. BTW, this code still has some debug stuff in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing your arguments correctly.

```
def runFile(model, datafile, time_scale, max_PEs, tank_address_dict, PMT_dict, channel_ref):

hawc_func.runFile(model,data,4000,TankDict,PTMDict,time_scale,channel_ref)
```

Here, you have `max_PEs = TankDict`.

That may not be your only problem. Fix that first, and if you are still having problems, update your post with your fixed code and then tell us what your new error is.

Comment: I suggest you use keyword args. As in `runFile(model=None, datafile=None, ...)` etc. If you do this, you will need to make sure that you do not call the function without defining all of the arguments - but this ought to help you avoid getting the arguments wrong.